# Best Algorithm to make correction typos in text

Tags: python, string, algorithm, nlp, pattern-matching

I have a list of word library and a text in which there are a spell error (typos), and I want to correct the word spell error to be correct according to list of library

for example

in list of word :

`listOfWord = [...,"halo","saya","sedangkan","semangat","cemooh"..];`

this is my string :

`string = "haaallllllooo ssya sdngkan ceemoooh , smngat semoga menyenangkan"`

I want change the spellerror to be correct like :

`string = "halo saya sedangkan cemooh, semangat semoga menyenangkan"`

what is the best algorithm to check each word in list, because I have millions of words in the list and have many possibilities

Comment: Why do you need the best algorithm? It's probably a trade secret and extremely complex. How good does your solution need to be?

Comment: I just want to know the best algorithm to find this solution, and I have tried but took a long time in its process, because I use bruteforce technique @PeterWood

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how your data is stored, but you'll probably want to use a pattern matching algorithm like [Aho–Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). Of course, that assumes your input data structure is a Trie. A [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) a very space-efficient storage container for words that may also be of interest to you (again, depending on your environment.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `difflib`'s get close matches, though it is not that efficient.

```
words = ["halo","saya","sedangkan","semangat","cemooh"]
def get_exact_words(input_str):
    exact_words = difflib.get_close_matches(input_str,words,n=1,cutoff=0.7)
    if len(exact_words)>0:
        return exact_words[0]
    else:
        return input_str

string = "haaallllllooo ssya sdngkan ceemoooh , smngat semoga menyenangkan"
string = string.split(' ')
exact = [get_exact_words(word) for word in string]

exact = ' '.join(exact)
print(exact)
```

Output :
With `difflib`

haaallllllooo saya sedangkan cemooh , semangat semangat menyenangkan

Comment: I think there is an algorithm to look for stacks of strings, but this answer is very helpful at all, I just found out there is a library like this in python :)

Comment: This works extremely well given you have a large vocabulary of correct words. Also pure python :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are writing spell checker for some language.

You might want tokenize the sentence into words.

Then shorten words like `haaallllllooo` to `haalloo`. Assuming the language you have doesn't have words that have many repeated letters too often. Easy to check since you have the dictionary.

Then you can use this [algorithm/implementation by Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html). All you have to do is to replace his dictionary of correct words with your dictionary.

Comment: It still won't correct `haalloo` to `halo` because Peter Norvig's spell checker is hard-coded to find only corrections with LD <= 2 (this example has LD == 3).

Comment: Thanks for the link of Peter Norvig's implementation. I knew it is out there, but I couldn't remember the exact name of his article. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hashing techniques for checking correct pattern, something on the lines of [Rabin Karp Algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

You know what would be the hash value of your original strings in the list. For spell correction, you can try the combination of those words that gives you same hash value before matching them with original string present in the dictionary. This would require, anyways, to iterate through all the characters in the spellerror list only once. But it will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyenchant to check spelling with your list of words.

```
>>> import enchant
>>> d = enchant.request_pwl_dict("mywords.txt")
>>> d.check('helo')
False
>>> d.suggest("Helo")
['He lo', 'He-lo', 'Hello', 'Helot', 'Help', 'Halo', 'Hell', 'Held', 'Helm', 'Hero', "He'll"]
```

You need to split your words and check one-by-one, choose the first suggestion to replace if it's false.
There are more advance features in the tutorial here.
http://pyenchant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: The documentation seems to have moved to http://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/

Answer (score -1):

I think you should apply string distance algorithms with a word to find nearest. You can apply [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithms to find the nearest word. Those are mostly O(n) algorithms so at the end your sentence replacement would cost you O(n) at most.